# Access SQL Rolling 12 months Distinct Count

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, distinct

I have two tables in MS Access, one **Dates** with just a list of months and years, eg:

`MonthNumber  YearNumber
  1             2013
  2             2013
  3             2013`

The second table is **Bedfile** which lists the clients namecode, the date, month, and year of their stay, eg:

`Namecode  Date      Month  Year
  Bob      1/1/2013   1      2013
  Joe      1/1/2013   1      2013
  Bob      1/2/2013   1      2013
  Joe      1/2/2013   1      2013
  Eric     1/2/2013   1      2013
  Bob      2/15/2013  2      2013
  Joe      2/16/2013  2      2013
  Bob      2/1/2014   2      2014
  Joe      2/1/2014   2      2014`

### What I'm looking for

I'm currently trying to make a query that counts the distinct namecodes for the twelve months prior, eg:

`MonthResults  YearResults CountResults
  1               2013        3
  2               2013        3
  2               2014        2`

This will be a *rolling* query, meaning that the results column will display the count of the namecodes found within the 12 months prior.

### My **first** SQL attempt is:

`SELECT 
dates.monthnumber,
 dates.yearnumber, 
(
SELECT Count(a.namecode)
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT bedfile.namecode FROM BEDFILE
   WHERE bedfile.date 
   BETWEEN dateserial(dates.yearnumber-1, dates.monthnumber, datepart("d", bedfile.date))
   AND dateserial(dates.yearnumber, dates.monthnumber, datepart("d", bedfile.date))
   ) as a
)
FROM dates
GROUP BY dates.yearnumber, dates.monthnumber`

When I run this, it asks me what the dates.yearnumber and dates.monthnumer are. If I input numbers (say, 2013 and 1 respectively) it gives me the distinct count for only that month.

### My **second** attempt is this:

`SELECT Count(a.namecode), dates.monthnumber, dates.yearnumber
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT bedfile.namecode, bedfile.month, bedfile.year 
   FROM BEDFILE 
   WHERE bedfile.date 
   BETWEEN dateadd("yyyy", -1, bedfile.date) and bedfile.date
   )  AS a 
INNER JOIN dates 
ON (a.month=dates.monthnumber) AND (a.year=dates.yearnumber)
GROUP BY dates.yearnumber, dates.monthnumber;`

This second query gives me the distinct counts, but only for each month, rather than the sum of the previous 12.

Does anyone know how to help me create what I'm looking for? Is it even possible in an Access SQL query?

Comment: do you want the 12 months prior or for the year? aka.. for the year 2013 do you want the number per distinct namecode? or from march 2012 - march 2013 do you want the count?

Comment: I want from march 2012 - march 2013.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    first_date,
    second_date,
    COUNT(name) as num_distinct,
    name
FROM(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT b.namecode AS name,
        b.date AS first_date,
        DateAdd("yyyy",-1,[b.date]) AS second_date
    FROM bedfile b
    WHERE b.date BETWEEN DateAdd("yyyy",-1,[b.date]) AND b.date
)
GROUP BY name
```

not sure if this is correct since i've never used MS Access SQL but it seems like this would work

---

EDIT:

you said that this query

```
SELECT Count(a.namecode), dates.monthnumber, dates.yearnumber
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT bedfile.namecode, bedfile.month, bedfile.year 
   FROM BEDFILE 
   WHERE bedfile.date 
   BETWEEN dateadd("yyyy", -1, bedfile.date) and bedfile.date
   )  AS a 
INNER JOIN dates 
ON (a.month=dates.monthnumber) AND (a.year=dates.yearnumber)
GROUP BY dates.yearnumber, dates.monthnumber;
```

returns the distinct count per month so **why not just  wrap it with another select that selects the SUM() of your count** to get the sum per year? **another thing you can do is remove the GROUP BY dates.monthnumber**.... because that is going to split the data by month instead of showing a year.

I would recommend just grouping by year as it's less sql to write and easier to read.

Comment: DATE(a.date) is just to ensure that the date you have listed is in a date format with no timestamp.

Comment: Count(distinct) does not work in MS Access version of SQL. It's a huge pain for stuff like this. Also, is subdate a function for Access?

Comment: sorry lol I thought it was mysql.. gimme a sec let me see if i can build a query.. never used MS Access SQL

Comment: Ok just edited my answer with another query, let me know if that works :D

Comment: you may need to add a group by in the sub query.. i don't know if the DateAdd groups the data like an aggregate function does

Comment: Thanks for your help John.  I ran your query and but it doesn't generate the results I want. Because you included the two dates in the subquery SELECT DISTINCT statement, it doesn't give me the proper count. I want it to pull all the distinct names between those dates in the WHERE part.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I can't just sum 12 months worth to get the year amounts. If a name pops up in February, and then in May, it will be counted in each of the month-counts, but I only want it counted once in the year count.

Comment: ok i went ahead and built a fiddle. I believe I got it how you want it. here is the fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b898/11  ------ I know its in mysql, but those functions are all general to all SQL

Comment: your problem is you were selecting distinct names per month, so I just selected the year and a distinct name.. let me know if you want the month and I can edit the fiddle.... it just seems like the month is pointless since its all data within a year for one row

Comment: I checked out the fiddle.  thanks for putting work into this for me.  Unfortunately, it doesn't do exactly what I'm asking for because its grouping on the calendar year. that's helpful, but it is not a rolling 12 month query.  I may just have to export the bulk data and use excel to make what I'm looking for.